# error TS1046: 'declare' modifier required for top level element

Tags: typescript

I'm using a `.d.ts` definition file I found online for interoperating with a JavaScript library.

I'm seeing the error message:

> TS1046: 'declare' modifier required for top level element

What is causing this?

I'm using TypeScript 0.9.1.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This was a breaking change between 0.8.x vs 0.9.x. `declare` is now required for all top level non-interface elements (i.e. `module`, `class`, `var`) in a declaration `.d.ts` file:

[image]

[Source: Microsoft Blog](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Known%20breaking%20changes%20between%200.8%20and%200.9)

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript 0.9 is not backwards compatible with prior versions. You must prefix the top level element (probably a `module`) with the `declare` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

in your package.json-> devDependencies part insert
"fast-deep-equal": "^3.0.0",

than it should function